# Get substring before the second capital letter

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Is there an **R** function to get only the part of a string before the 2nd capital character appears?

For example:

```
Example <- "MonkeysDogsCats"
```

Expected output should be:

```
"Monkeys"
```

Comment: Which answer worked for you? Are you able to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
stringr::str_extract("MonkeysDogsCats", "[A-Z][a-z]*")
#[1] "Monkeys"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution with `sub()`:

```r
x <- "MonkeysDogsCats"

sub("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z].*", "", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Monkeys"
```

Another way using `stringr::word()`:

```r
stringr::word(x, 1, sep = "(?=[A-Z])\\B")
# [1] "Monkeys"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

Here we first put a space before all uppercase and then extract the first word:

```
library(stringr)

word(gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])","\\1 \\2", Example), 1)

[1] "Monkeys"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is strictly to capture any *string before the 2nd capital character*, one might want pick a solution it'll also work with all types of strings including numbers and special characters.

```r
strings <- c("MonkeysDogsCats",
             "M4DogsCats",
             "M?DogsCats")

stringr::str_remove(strings, "(?<=.)[A-Z].*")
```

Output:

```r
[1] "Monkeys"  "M4"  "M?"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to allow to match. You can for example match an uppercase char `[A-Z]` optionally followed by any character that is not an uppercase character `[^A-Z]*`

If you don't want to allow whitespace chars, you can exclude them `[^A-Z\\s]*`

```
library(stringr)

str_extract("MonkeysDogsCats", "[A-Z][^A-Z]*")
```

**Output**

```
[1] "Monkeys"
```

[R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJNLAQi4gLz41IqSosTkEg0l3/y87NTKYpf89GLnxJJiJR0FpWhH3ajY6DgQqaWk@f8/AA)

---

If there should be an uppercase character following, and there are only lowercase characters allowed:

```
str <- "MonkeysDogsCats"
regmatches(str, regexpr("[A-Z][a-z]*(?=[A-Z])", str, perl = TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
[1] "Monkeys"
```

[R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikSMFGV0HJNz8vO7Wy2CU/vdg5saRYiasoNT03sSQ5I7VYA6hGRwHIT60oKNJQinbUjYqNTtStitXSsLcF8zSVdBTAigpSi3IUbBVCgkJdNTX//wcA)